# Is there a way to report incorrect login attempts in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu, security, logs, login

I am concerned with some people trying to access my laptop while I am away in my work place.

Therefore I was wondering if is there a way to set up kind of automatically monitor and report wrong password login attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are utility commands named `last` and `lastb` to list the logins and attempted logins on most Unix distributions.  In your case you might want to try the `lastb` command to see the failures.  As stated before you will need to be root to see these logs.

Answer (score 10):

All login attempts (successful or failed) are recorded in `/var/log/auth.log`. The file is rotated every week, so look in `/var/log/auth.log.0` for the previous week's logs, `/var/log/auth.log.1.gz` for the week before, etc. By default, 4 weeks are kept.

On other distributions, the principles are the same, but the name of the file may be different (always in `/var/log` under Linux and most other unix variants), and the rotation periods are very distribution-dependent.

You will need to be root to see those logs. There are programs like [`logwatch`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/logwatch) that you can set up to monitor logs and send you “interesting” lines by email, but I think setting this up is overkill for your situation.